# sql loader load multiple lines from one line

Tags: oracle

I'm facing an issue loading a file with sql loader.

This is what my input file looks like:

```
#ID; CARD_NUMBER;USERNAME  
1;86730975,86536522,86793501;JOHN SMITH  
2;89734562;MICHAEL ABOT  
3;87903546,87265390;JAMES ALBERT
```

And what I want to acheive after loading is this:

```
#Table data
1;86730975;JOHN SMITH  
1;86536522;JOHN SMITH  
1;86793501;JOHN SMITH  
2;89734562;MICHAEL ABOT  
3;87903546;JAMES ALBERT  
3;87265390;JAMES ALBERT
```

I did something like this before using Sql Loader, but I can't find the source code. So if someone can help that'll be very nice for me.

I'm new to this forum and I don't know how to find all the posts related to my username, I'll appreciate if someone can help on that to.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with external tables. To me personally it'll be a more convenient way to get it done:

1. Create a directory in Oracle that points to the exact location of the file on the server.

   ```
   SQL> create or replace directory ff1 as 'c:\';

   directory created
   ```
2. Create external table similar to this one:

   ```
   SQL> create table t1(
     2    t1_id      number,
     3    card_no    varchar2(4000),
     4    user_name  varchar2(4000)
     5  )
     6  organization external(
     7    type oracle_loader
     8    default directory ff1
     9    access parameters(
    10      records delimited by newline
    11      fields terminated by ';'
    12    )
    13    location('input.dat') --<-- file name
    14  ) reject limit unlimited
    15  ;

    Table created.
   ```

After that, you can query that external table, and use any (there are many of them) method to split comma separated string. In this case it would be values of `card_number`. For example:

This is the actual data:

```
SQL> column card_no format a40;
SQL> column user_name format a17;

SQL> select * from t1;

     T1_ID CARD_NO                                  USER_NAME
---------- ---------------------------------------- -----------------
         1 86730975,86536522,86793501               JOHN SMITH
         2 89734562                                 MICHAEL ABOT
         3 87903546,87265390                        JAMES ALBERT

3 rows selected.
```

Transformed version of actual data:

```
SQL> column card_no format 9999999999;

SQL> with ocrs(ocr) as(
  2    select level
  3      from ( select max(regexp_count(card_no, '[^,]+')) as mx
  4               from t1 ) s
  5     connect by level <= s.mx
  6  )
  7  select *
  8    from (select t.t1_id
  9               , to_number(regexp_substr(t.card_no, '[^,]+', 
 10                                         1, o.ocr)) as card_no
 11               , t.user_name
 12            from t1 t
 13           cross join ocrs o ) w
 14    where w.card_no is not null
 15   order by w.t1_id;
```

Result:

```
      T1_ID     CARD_NO USER_NAME
----------- ----------- -----------------
          1    86730975 JOHN SMITH
          1    86793501 JOHN SMITH
          1    86536522 JOHN SMITH
          2    89734562 MICHAEL ABOT
          3    87265390 JAMES ALBERT
          3    87903546 JAMES ALBERT

6 rows selected.
```

Having done that, you can use simple `insert` statement combined with the above query to insert new, transformed data into another table.

```
 insert into another_table(id, card_number, user_name)
    with ocrs(ocr) as(
      select level
    .....  
    /* the above query */
```